# Find the pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

The question is:

Consider the sequence $$ f_k(x):(0,1)\to \Bbb R\ $$ given by $$f_k(x)=kx^{k}$$ and find its pointwise limit.

Without the (0,1), I'd say the sequence diverges but now we have the interval (0,1) I tried to say that $|x^{k}|<1$ converges, but I am not sure how to then find the pointwise limit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HINT: What is "bigger", the infinity of a polynomial or the infinity of an exponetial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k>\dfrac x{1-x}$. We have

$$\frac{f_{k+1}(x)}{f_k(x)}=\frac{k+1}{k}x=r<1$$

so that by induction

$$f_{k+n}(x)<f_k(x)r^n$$ where the RHS is a decreasing geometric sequence.